# Sound Clip used to work but not anymore! what could be wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, audio

I have a sound clip that plays when `ViewDidLoad` and it used to work on the simulator. However, when I tried it on my device it stopped working at all!! not even the the simulator.

here is my code:

```
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Nouh", CFSTR("wav"), NULL);
UInt32 soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

Now what I'm sure of is that the code works perfect since I have used another clip and it plays. Also, the clip itself is working fine in xcode player.

I have tried deleting the reference, as well as, renaming the file itself and adding it again.

I remember I have moved my project from another computer but the whole project seems to me working fine, I dunno if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: When you moved the project are you sure the sound file got moved as well?  Can you locate it in the project folder?

Comment: @RichardBrown yes it's there! As I said, I have deleted the reference and renamed it and added it again! Plus, when I click on the file in xcode it's there and still working!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Sure it's not longer than 30 Sec as `AudioToolBox` will only play clips of 30 Sec and less.

If you need to play a clip longer than 30 Sec try `AVAudioPlayer`

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you very much! my clip was exactly `30 sec` but I have edited to make it `29` and it **worked**!!